# Routing in separate files with express 4.13

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have poblem with routing in express 4.13

Here is my index.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var wagner = require("wagner-core");
var morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('combined'));

require ('./models')(wagner);

var api = require("./api");

app.use('/api/v1', api);


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server Started!!!");
});
```

And this is file with routes:

```
var express = require("express");
// var status = require("http-status");

module.exports = function() {

    var api = express.Router();

    api.get("/category/id/:id", function(req,res){
        console.log("TEST")
        res.send("TEST");
    });

}
```

After I visit http://localhost:3000/api/v1/category/id/123 page just loadin and nothing happend... Anyone know what is problem?

Answer (score 3):

Move `var api = express.Router();` out of the exported object.

```
var express = require("express");
var api = express.Router();

api.get("/category/id/:id", function(req,res){
    console.log("TEST")
    res.send("TEST");
});

module.exports = api;
```

Because you need to mount a ready to use router module on the main app.

The exported object needs to be a route handler itself.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work?

```
var api = express.Router();

api.get("/category/id/:id", function(req,res){
    console.log("TEST")
    res.send("TEST");
});

module.exports = api;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found issue in my code.... I did't return router.

Inside function shoud be:

`return api;`